# Cocoa - prevent window from getting overlapped

Tags: cocoa, macos

I'm writing an app that should remain visible on the desktop at all times. As such, I have to prevent other apps' windows moving on top of my app's window.

The Dock.app from Mac OS X partially does this: if you resize windows, they won't resize into the Dock.app's screen space, and if you hit the windows' '+' button, the window will not cover the dock.

Is it possible to replicate this functionality, and if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Hello, ryyst. Did you find the way to implement this behavior?

Comment: It may be worth looking into the source code of tiling window managers, e.g. [chunkwm](https://github.com/koekeishiya/chunkwm) or [Amethyst](https://github.com/ianyh/Amethyst).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well it will work and it definitely requires "Enable access for assistive devices" to be enabled in the "Universal Access" system preference panel, but you could try using the [Accessibility Hierarchy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Accessibility/cocoaAXOverview/cocoaAXOverview.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001057-BBCJHHGJ) to monitor window frame changes of all on-screen windows and further manipulate them as desired.

Comment: Ah. I see what you're looking for. Updated answer.

Comment: Yes. Software development usually is.